# Ошибки в формировании html разметки через php

Tags: php, битрикс

Код выводит цифры, как положено:

```
    <?$sticker = "";
if (array_key_exists("PROPERTIES", $arResult) && is_array($arResult["PROPERTIES"]))
        {                   
        foreach (Array("STOCK" => "Акция", "INFICTION"=>"") as $propertyCode => $propertyCodeName)

            if (array_key_exists($propertyCode, $arResult["PROPERTIES"]) && intval($arResult["PROPERTIES"][$propertyCode]["PROPERTY_VALUE_ID"]) > 0)
                {  
                $arFiltrum = $arResult["PROPERTIES"]['INFICTION']["VALUE_XML_ID"];                                  

                if($propertyCode == "STOCK") $sticker .= '<span class="xit" style="font-size:20px;"';

                if(in_array("INF1",$arFiltrum)) $sticker .= "1";                                        
                if(in_array("INF2",$arFiltrum)) $sticker .= "2";
                if(in_array("INF3",$arFiltrum)) $sticker .= "3";                                                    
                if(in_array("INF4",$arFiltrum)) $sticker .= "4";                                                    
                if(in_array("INF5",$arFiltrum))$sticker .= "5";

                $sticker .= '>'.$propertyCodeName.'</span>';

                }
        }
?>
```

Значение в каждом `(in_array("INF1-INF5",$arFiltrum))` - `true`.
 Но если я вставляю вместо чисел, пытаюсь вставить картинки

```
$sticker .= '<span class="xits" style="font-size:20px; background: url(/tamp.png) 1px -1px no-repeat;left:70px;"';                                                          
$sticker .= '<span class="xits" style="font-size:20px; background: url(/gravirovka.png) 1px -1px no-repeat;"';
$sticker .= '<span class="xits" style="font-size:20px; background: url(/uf_print.png) 1px -1px no-repeat;"';
$sticker .= '<span class="xits" style="font-size:20px; background: url(/sticker.png) 1px -1px no-repeat;"';
$sticker .= '<span class="xits" style="font-size:20px; background: url(/label.png) 1px -1px no-repeat;"';
```

То выводит только первую картинку. Проблемы со стилями отпадают, потому что без условий все картинки нормально выводятся.

Comment: «Не работает условие» — вы имеете в виду, что оператор `if` в PHP неправильно работает?

Comment: Имею ввиду, что в моём коде не срабатывает условие, может кто-то заметит ошибку, которую я не вижу.

Comment: @Николай, просить пользователей ru.SO поработать синтаксическими анализаторами кода, как минимум, не вежливо.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev я прошу помочь, а не анализаторами. Потому что я не понимаю где здесь ошибка.

Comment: @Николай берете отладчик и смотрите как ваш код работает...

Comment: @Николай я у вас не вижу `$` в последней строке перед именем переменной и закрывающий `</span>` может нужен (да и `>` еще)?

Comment: @RussCoder, имя переменной исправил,  скопировалось неправильно. Всё остальное есть: `$sticker .= '>'.$propertyCodeName.'</span>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($propertyCode == "STOCK") $sticker .= '<span class="xit" style="font-size:20px;"';

                if(in_array("INF1",$arFiltrum)) $sticker .= "1";                                        
                if(in_array("INF2",$arFiltrum)) $sticker .= "2";
                if(in_array("INF3",$arFiltrum)) $sticker .= "3";                                                    
                if(in_array("INF4",$arFiltrum)) $sticker .= "4";                                                    
                if(in_array("INF5",$arFiltrum))$sticker .= "5";

                $sticker .= '>'.$propertyCodeName.'</span>';
```

Тут у вас ошибки.
Во-первых, даже цифры добаляются до `>`, то есть они не внутри элементов, а среди атрибутов.
Во-вторых, если вы добавляете

```
$sticker .= '<span class="xits" style="font-size:20px; background: url(/tamp.png) 1px -1px no-repeat;left:70px;"';
```

То делаете это  5 раз, а тег закрываете только 1 раз. Надо закрывать тег каждый раз  да и в начале лучше сразу написать

```
if($propertyCode == "STOCK") $sticker .= '<span class="xit" style="font-size:20px;">';
```

С закрывающей `>`.